# iOS: Issues concerning heights of views

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

In this application I am working on, I am noticing that when I set `tab.navigationBar.translucent = YES;`, the content view does not go all the way to the bottom of the page.

However when I set it to NO, it does.

[image]

The height isn't being explicitly set to a value. Due to this observation, I think another problem I am having regarding the scroller not going all the way down to the bottom of the page is happening.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try in iOS 6 Simulator and see if the problem exists there too !
If not, it's a problem regarding layout. Post the result here when you tested in iOS 6 simulator

Comment: By the way, this problem is existing in the iOS 7 simulator. I'll try the iOS 6 one though. Good suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if apple did it this way or not, but htey might have put a UIVIew object behind the navigation bar when translucent is NO. That might be why there is equal room when using no, because there is a UIView object above it. Not an answer, just a suggestion...

Comment: So do you think this is affecting the issue I am having regarding the scroller not going all the way down to the bottom on the page?

Comment: Since you are trying to set the translucent property of the navigation bar to YES, I am guessing you want the content to be visible as it scrolls under the nav bar. For this, you will need to explicitly set the contentOffset value to a convenient value (about 64.0 should be fine.).

Comment: Where would I set contentOffset?

Comment: Setting iOS 6/7 Delta to 64 ( when viewing as iOS 6 ) or -64 ( when viewing as iOS 7 ) would suffice I guess !

Comment: Which file do I find iOS 6/7 Delta?